# Download file and the user decides where to locate it

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have this problem, I am looking for how to download an AWS Bucket file, but not download it on the client and decide where to save it, which is not working.

```js
$S3Options = 
[
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' =>[
        'key' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx'
    ],
    'scheme' => 'http'
];

$s3 =  new Aws\S3\S3Client($S3Options);

$getFile = $s3->getObject(
    [
        'Key' => 'xxxx/'.$archivo[1],
        'Bucket' => 'xxxxxxx',

    ]);

$getFile = $getFile->toArray();
file_put_contents($archivo[1],$getFile['Body']);
```

Comment: Please specify how it is not working. Does the user not get the file? Or did the browser failed to show a download dialog and show the file directly on the browser?

Comment: the browser was unable to display a download dialog

Comment: Wait. I'm a bit confused. Do you want the server to download and store the file from S3? Or do you want the user (client) to have it?

Comment: I want the user to have that file, as I have it, I download it to the server and the user does not see it

Answer (score 0):

First, [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) would save the file to the server instead of the client. You need to directly display the content to client. The easiest way is echo:

```php
echo $getFile['Body'];
```

To force the user download a file (instead of showing it on browser), you need to provide a header that a browser does not know how to handle directly.

```php
$S3Options =  [
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' =>[
        'key' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx'
    ],
    'scheme' => 'http',
];

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client($S3Options);

$getFile = $s3->getObject([
    'Key' => 'xxxx/'.$archivo[1],
    'Bucket' => 'xxxxxxx',
]);

$getFile = $getFile->toArray();

// ** Add header call here **
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); // this is the most important line
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
// ** header end **

echo $getFile['Body'];
```

Now the browser will know to download the file instead of showing, but it does not guarantee the browser would prompt user for the save location.

The download behaviour differs between browsers. And most browser also give user options for it to "save to default location without asking". If the user set their browser to save without asking, he would never get a dialog.

Comment: it is not downloading the file for me, try your headers but it does not download on client or server

Comment: What did you see instead?